# how to delete record in two tables using query in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig, dql

I'm new to symfony , I'm stuck in delete option , I wrote a query that is working fine but i need to delete same record in different table also(Same record i have in 2 tables)

my controller

```
 public function deleteAction(Request $request){
    $deleteQuery = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->delete('TcPlayerBundle:TcTracks', 'd')
    ->where('d.id = ' . $request->get('id'))->getQuery();
    $deleted = $deleteQuery->getResult();

    $deleted->flush();
    return $this->render('TcPlayerBundle:Default:all.html.twig',array(
            'tracks' => $tracks
    ));
}
```

this query is working fine for single table , how to do inner join with another table 
TcprofileBundle:TcWall and the id in that table is related_id . pls help me with solutions, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$tcTrack = $em->getRepository('TcPlayerBundle:TcTracks')->find($request->get('id'));
$em->remove($tcTrack);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: If i do that with remove function() means it wont delete in two  tables , i need to call back the function to another table , so for that i went with query with innerjoint to delete, if i delete in one table automatically record in another table should be deleted

Comment: Just call the function `findBy` (you'll provide the parameters, like `array('track_id' => $id))` for both repositores and `remove` each one of the.